# dayClick FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Tem como evitar de abrir o `prompt(modal)` de inserção de novo evento ao **clicar** em um dia no `monthView`? Eu consegui ele fazer ir para a data clicada no `agendaWeek` mas ele continua abrindo o `prompt` para inserção de novo evento.

**CÓDIGO:**

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
    //não abrir o prompt de inserção
    //no caso eu quero apenas que vá para a agendaWeek na data clicada
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu consegui a resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33937947/5494359).

O que acontece é que eu tenho que verificar, na hora do dayClick se a view atual é a 'month' e fazer o prompt abrir se não for.

```
select: function(start, end) {
    if($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').type != 'month'){
        //ele somente entra para cadastrar se a view não for a 'month'.
    }
    else{
        //se for a 'month view' ele passa pelo if e entra neste else, alterando entao a view para agendaWeek e, portanto, nao abrindo o prompt de inserção
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
    }
}
```

Comment: poste um pedaço do codigo e nao só link :D

Comment: Ok, editado!!!!